# Cloning knockout observables with lodash.clonedeep

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, knockout.js, lodash

I needed some ideas regarding my current issue...

I'm currently improving a small but common part of a big software. This means I may not replace functionality without creating extreme testing overhead or even impacting functionality.

I'm trying to clone a data structure that besides normal data contains lots of knockout observables. Doing this I see serious performance differences between Chrome and IE.
It could be possible that there are cyclic references, it could also be possible, that knockout observables somehow do not like being cloned. Or perhaps the Internet 
Explorer reached some kind of data size limit that can be extended. Whatever the reason is, Chrome somehow does better.

The problem gets intensified because of these reasons:

I need this huge data structure of several tens of thousands "beautified JSON"(!!) lines to simulate 
real life and to create this big problem. This amount of data may not be diminished to a debugable extent because the smaller the data is, the less the timing 
difference to find and finally it vanishes. To publish the data structure is also not possible for me because I'm not able to make such an amount of data anonymous. And with this 
size of data it is not really possible to find data problems while debugging.

I do not think that Google is that superior to Microsoft, so I expect the problem to be data dependent or to be able to be eliminated by some browser settings.
Overall in the internet I can read, that lodash.clonedeep() would be slow or that the Internet Explorer would be slow. If so, this may not be my problem. In my opinion this does not explain the huge differences on Chrome an the Internet Explorer. 
Such an answer is too simple for me and I need some improvement because most of our customers use the Internet Explorer and this is impossible to change.

I did run the following lines in Chrome and Internet Explorer.

```
console.time('jquery.extend()');
dataCopy = $.extend(true, {}, viewModel.api.getData());
console.timeEnd('jquery.extend()');
console.time('lodash.clonedeep()');
dataCopy = _.cloneDeep(viewModel.api.getData());
console.timeEnd('lodash.clonedeep()');
console.time('JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())');
dataCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(viewModel.api.getData()));
console.timeEnd('JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())');
```

The output is as follows

```
Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94:
jquery.extend(): 1159.470947265625ms
lodash.clonedeep(): 2783.241943359375ms
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()): 1139.403076171875ms

Internet Explorer Version 11.0.9600.18837:
jquery.extend(): 10.802,27ms
lodash.clonedeep(): 28.302,65ms
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()): 10.479,681ms
```

Does anybody have an idea regarding

- why this huge difference exists?
- a way to accelerate IE (almost) to the speed of Chrome in this context?
- a hint what to look at? / to find out what the problem is?
- a way to find out what is going on in lodash.clonedeep() with such huge data? (Something more efficient than breakpoints.)
- possible debug output messages from anywhere that could help?
- is there a known impact of knockout observables to lodash.clonedeep() on IE?
- whether knockout observables somehow do not like to be cloned?
- whether cyclic structures are a problem for cloning at all? (If so, why is Chrome that faster?)

I'm searching for resolutions as well as for best practices.

Thanks to all of you!

Comment: Do you want your observables to be preserved as observables in the clone?

Comment: Have a look at [ko.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) and [ko.toJS](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html).

Comment: Do I need it the observables to be preserved as observables?  
                      Do be honest I do not know.                            

I had a deeper look in this part of the code ... The copy that is made is for finding out changes later in order to determine whether changes need to be saved of not. This ends up in calling "lodash.isEqual()".
This searching for changes is the only reason for the copy. In case there would be a more efficient way (10 times faster) to do this, I would make a huge step ahead.

Comment: Sounds like you don't need them to be observables, which is good, as I don't think you can clone things that way. Try timing tests using `ko.toJS` to clone the structure.

Comment: Sorry for the delaied answer. I had some days off before Christmas...

I did some timing tests with ko.JS()

`Internet Explorer: 
ko.toJS(): 49.052,202ms
<br/>    


Chrome:
ko.toJS(): 1826.697998046875ms
    
The code:
console.time('ko.toJS()');
dataCopy = ko.toJS(viewModel.api.getData());
console.timeEnd('ko.toJS()');`
   
The idea was really good, but I does not solve the problem. I would be glad if you had another idea.